# Identities for products

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are many identities for $\sum$ but I can barely find useful ones for $\prod$. Specifically, I can expand

$$
\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq N} (x_j^2 - 2 x_j x_i + x_i^2)
$$

to a large sum involving terms of the form $x_1^{k_1} x_2^{k_2} \cdots x_N^{k_N}$ but I am unable to derive an analytic relationship.

My goal is ending up with a sum (or sums) where each term is parameterized. Can anybody think about a formal expansion or does it not exist?

Comment: Take a log of your expression?

Comment: I thought about that one but that does not help. The reason why I want to have a sum is because $X_i$ are iid RVs and I need to wrap the expectation operator around it. That way I could determine which terms are zero and which to consider. With log/det that gets complicted ...

Answer (score 0):

This is the square of the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix, and there's an extensive theory about it.

See, for example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Good observation - but this is precicely where I'm coming from ;-) I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}\det \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$ when the nodes are Gaussian iid. Which results in the formula above. All terms which will contain an odd power will be zero and for the rest a simple expression could be found. But first it would need to be translated to a sum of products (rather than a product of sums/differences)...

Comment: Would the usual determinant formula give you the sum of products that you're looking for?  It's a bit unwieldy, of course.

Comment: You mean Laplace expansion? Probably but I wanted to avoid that complicated formula ;-) Also, I would need to square the whole thing afterwards. I'll have another look at this.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, and you probably realize this already, but you can avoid squaring by replacing your product with $\prod_{i\ne j} (x_i-x_j).$